# undefined method `last_page? in link_to_next_page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kaminari

I m using `kaminari gem`
In my events_controller

```
def show
 ...
 @comments = @event.comments.page(params[:page]).limit(5)
  respond_to do |format|
   format.js
   format.html       
 end
end
```

in my `events/show.html.haml`

```
.row
 .load-more
  = render :partial => 'comments/comment', :collection => @comments, locals: {event_show: true}
  = link_to_next_page @comments, 'Load More', :remote => true, :id=>"load_more_link"
```

in my show.js.erb

```
$('..load-more').append("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => @comments)%>");
$('#load_more_link').replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript(link_to_next_page(@comments, 'Load More', :remote => true, :id=>'load_more_link'))%>");
```

Reference SO [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5543719/rails-3-kaminari-jquery-load-more-button-problem-to-display-results-it-loads)

I m getting this error

```
undefined method `last_page?' for <Comment::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:0x007fe0931c5860>
```

in

```
= link_to_next_page @comments, 'Load More', :remote => true, :id=>"load_more_link"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: paste your full controller please.

Comment: where is your `last_page?` defined?

Comment: @sugaryourcoffee there is no last_page? . it is a method provided by Kaminari

Comment: @matanco: only that code is relative to comments, also i have tested '@comments' object and it is not nil .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution 
Kaminari have fix for the problem in latest version but it is not working if u have:

```
gem 'kaminari'
```

Change it to

```
gem 'kaminari', :git => 'git@github.com:amatsuda/kaminari.git'
```

This will remove the error. 
Thanks

Comment: this requires an SSH key "id_rsa"